# Stuck at infinite loop at enter weight and profit of elements

Tags: java, eclipse, output, infinite, knapsack-problem

Getting stuck at an infinite loop at enter weights and profits Does not move forward than that no matter how many outputs you enter
Any help would be appreciated
Here is the following code

```
import java.util.*;
import java.text.*;

class fracknapsack
{
public static void main(String args[])
{
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("##.##");
    System.out.println("Enter number of elements: ");
    int n = sc.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Enter total mass: ");
    float m = sc.nextFloat();
    System.out.println("Enter weight and profit of "+n+" elements: ");
    float w[] = new float[n];
    float p[] = new float[n];
    float r[] = new float[n];
    float f[] = new float[n];
    float max = (float)0;
    int flag = 0;
    //for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
    //{
    //    int a = sc.nextInt();
    //    w[i] = (float)a;
    //}
    //for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
    //{
    //    int b = sc.nextInt();
    //    p[i] = (float)b;
    //}
    
    for(int i=0; i<=n; i++)
    {
        int a = sc.nextInt();
        int b = sc.nextInt();
        w[i] = (float)a;
        p[i] = (float)b;
        r[i] = p[i]/w[i];
        f[i] = (float)0;
        if(p[i]>max)
        {
            max = p[i];
            flag = i;
        }
    }
     
    float tprofit = (float)0;
    while(m>0)
    {
        if(m>max)
        {
            tprofit = tprofit + p[flag];
            f[flag] = (float)1;
            m = m - max;
        }
        else
        {
            float fraction = max/m;
            tprofit = tprofit + p[flag]*fraction;
            f[flag] = fraction;
            max = 0;
        }
        float j = (float)0;
        for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
        {
            if(j>r[i] && j<max)
            {
                j = r[i];
                flag = i;
            }
        }
        max = j;
    }
    
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("Fraction of weights included: ");
    System.out.println("Weights \t|\t Fraction");
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        System.out.println(df.format(w[i])+"\t|\t"+df.format(f[i]));
    }
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("Total Profit = "+df.format(tprofit));
}}
```

This i believe should run properly but isnt.
Very confused what the problem could be.
Included another for loop just for testing, problem still persists.

Comment: What does the debugger (or various System.out.println() statements) tell you? What are the values of `m` and `max` for example, how do they behave and change?

Comment: It doesnt move forward, gets stuck at enter weight and profit of elements.

Comment: well, what is `n` in that case and how many ints do you enter afterwards?

Comment: n is length of the array

Comment: i know what it means, what value does it have?

Comment: By the way: **use the debugger** or add as many `System.out.println(...)` as possible** until you figure out what line / section of the code causes the problem. Right now you have a lot of logic and a lot can go wrong in a lot of places but you have no intermediary output at all.

Comment: im sorry im not following, its int. and based on knapsack problem. so like, the number of elements is stored, its total mass as well, and then enter the weight and profits based on the elements stored in the n

Comment: in your sample run is it 7 or 13 oder 0 or 1000000000? What value do you choose? Depending on `n` you then expect `(n+1) * 2` ints to be input on the command line.

Comment: okay, so i ran the debugger like you mentioned, big thanks and found that within the for loop, w[i]=(float)a; is the problem area. i however dont understand how

Comment: The previous statement `sc.nextInt()` blocks / waits until you enter an integer on the command line.

Comment: Longer, more description variable names will make your life way easier as a coder. Everyone is always says you should comment your code well, but I think that is wrong. I believe your variable names should make it clear what your code is doing, and you should only have to comment very complicated sections of code. [I recommend watching Uncle Bob's Clean Code on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7EmboKQH8lM). It taught me a lot about writing better code. Which makes going back and re-reading my own work much easier.

Comment: One general hint: you probably want to use ``double`` rather than ``float``. Unless you're storing huge arrays, there is almost no reason to use float rather than double.

Answer (score 0):

In line 32 (the first loop) you iterate one entry too often.
You want to fill all the n entries in the array - but you are filling n+1, when iterating from i=0 to i<=n

So I get an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException, when I try your code.

I fixed that, but result in an endless loop, because the "max" variable stays always 0 and m never changes (always stays greater 0).

As a general hint, you should name the variables with more speaking names and comment the code.

Comment: okay so i fixed the loop on line 32 to for(int i=0; i<n; i++) doesnt seem to make a difference and i still have the same endless loop problem at the enter weight and profits of elements.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned the for loop should run until `i < n` not `i <= n`

Here is your code commented to highlight the issue. You are never entering `if(j>r[i] && j<max)`:

```java
    while(m>0)
    {
        if(m>max)
        {
            tprofit = tprofit + p[flag];
            f[flag] = (float)1;
            m = m - max;
        }
        else
        {
            float fraction = max/m;
            tprofit = tprofit + p[flag]*fraction;
            f[flag] = fraction;
            max = 0; // issue: setting max == 0
        }
        float j = (float)0; // issue: setting j == 0 therefore line 66 is never true
        for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
        {
            if(j>r[i] && j<max) // issue: j=0 and max=0 therefore j < max == false
            { // issue: also, can r[i] be negative? That would mean a negative profit or mass therefore it is always the case that j>r[i] == false 
                j = r[i];
                flag = i;
            }
        }
        max = j; // we never entered the if statement so j==0. We will never enter the if statement on line 50 and we will now loop infinitely
    }
```

I (also) recommend using longer, more descriptive variable names. I can't tell what you are doing and I don't want to take the time to logicly reason it out, so I can't fix your broken `if` statement logic, but at least I can point you to the spot things are breaking.

Longer, more description variable names will make your life way easier as a coder. Everyone is always says you should comment your code well, but I think that is wrong. I believe your variable names should make it clear what your code is doing, and you should only have to comment very complicated sections of code. I recommend watching [Uncle Bob's Clean Code on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7EmboKQH8lM). It taught me a lot about writing better code. Which makes going back and re-reading my own work much easier.